# Android IOException in HTTPPost

Tags: java, android, http-post

I have a basic page set up online on my server which processes Post Data from like a html form. The page returns xml data if the post requirements are met (correct username etc.) else, a 0.

It works perfectly in a browser.

I am using httppost in android to post to this page, however, my try catch block is going into IOexception. First off, I don't know how to actually view what is the problem since I don't know where stacktrace prints to.

The web page code just gets post data `$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$user = $_POST["username"];` simple enough.

Is there anything I am supposed to be doing server side maybe?

Comment: If your are using Eclipse use the Debug or DDMS perspective's and look at the stacktrace in Logcat.

Comment: Have you added `android.permission.INTERNET` to your manifest?

Comment: dave c you've just rescued me from an hour of pulling my hair out! thank you. something so simple. My first time using android :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to add internet permission in manifest file.. d'oh! Thanks dave.c.

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```